# how to sync mongo databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

The main database is in my company's LAN.

The **2nd database** is on the AWS

The products' data will be **updated/created/deleted**  in the **main database**,

The customers will query from the **2nd database** on the AWS.

How to sync the **2nd database** with **main database** every **10 seconds** or **update on changing**

Comment: Why the constraint of every 10 seconds?

Comment: Can't agree with the sentiment of the preceding comments more strongly. If standard replica set configuration is not desired or possible, then you are basically asking for a program to handle this. A bit broad and opinionated for a canonical response in that case. Code to your requirements if you must.